# Искажение цвета изображения при сохранении JavaFX Canvas через ImageIO

Tags: javafx

Работаю над небольшим графическим редактором. Пытаюсь сохранить изображение в самых распространенных форматах типа jpg, png, bmp, tiff и получаю при этом искажение цвета с уходом в желтые тона. Пример приведен ниже и работает для сохранения в любом из перечисленных форматов подобным образом. Что делать?

```
WritableImage wImage = canvas.snapshot(null, new WritableImage(width, height));
RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(wImage, null);
ImageIO.write(renderedImage, extension, file);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключается в использовании формата ARGB, как я обнаружил. В обычном RGB все прекрасно работает и не происходит никакого искажения. 
`WritableImage wImage = canvas.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), new WritableImage(width, height));
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(wImage, null);
            BufferedImage bufferedImage1 = new BufferedImage(bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            bufferedImage1.getGraphics().drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null);
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage1, extension, file);`
Возможно, плохая реализация и можно было сделать проще.